# How to add delay between viewwillappear and viewdidappear in custom navigation?

Tags: ios

There is a delay between viewwillappear and viewdidappear when a view controller pushed to a navigation controller. Viewwillappear will be called immediatally, while viewdidappear will be called after the transation animation finished.

I want to make a custom navigation. Viewcontroller A is a container viewcontroller. It will contain viewcontroller B or viewcontroller C. At first, viewcontroller contains viewcontroller B(A is B's parent controller). Then controller B will navigate to controller C with a transation.

But viewdidappear will be called immediatally after viewwillappear, when addsubview is called. How to add delay between viewwillappear and viewdidappear? I hope viewwillappear will be called before the animation, and viewdidappear will be called after the animation. Can you help me?

Comment: There is a button in viewcontroller B's view. When tap the button, it will navigate to controller C. It looks like pushviewcontroller. The diffrence is, viewcontroller B will be dealloced.

Comment: I do not want to use navigationcontroller and pushviewcontrller, because there is a lot of viewcontrollers(viewcontroller D, viewcontroller E...), I do not want leave them in the memory when they are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way?

1. There is only one container - view controller A.
2. B, C, D... are all subviews instead of view controllers.
3. First, view controller A has view B by default.
4. And then click button in view B.
5. Do the animation for C and then in the completion block hide B or delete B.

Hopes this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to manually delay, try to put this in the bottom of `viewwillappear`

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  NSLog(@"Do some work");
});
```

Hope this could help.